# How do i check if certain page is being load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I´m developing an app with **cordova** in `Visual Studio`. And it was all good untill i get stuck on this problem.

I have an function that create some html code ("with append")getting all the infomation from my Data Base.

And i want to create it only when my html called "payments.html" finish loading.
or starts loading.

So it call my function and i get everything loaded to the user.

Is there any way to do it? with jquery? or javascript.
the only thing that i found was a code to check if html is loaded. but it doesn´t specify which one is getting load.

Comment: show us something....!

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask here

Comment: What are you creating, how are you creating, why are you creating. Give us some code to check ur problem and Please visit the help center to see how and what to ask here

Answer (score -1):

I think you want the [`$( document ).ready()`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) . It's a part of jQuery

Comment: _only thing that i found was a code to check if html is loaded_. He probably already knows about this (or an alternative).

Answer (score -2):

In Javascript you can check `location.href` which will give you complete URL of the current page.

```
if (-1 < location.href.indexOf('payment.html')) {
    cordova.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: It's not totally clear what the question is, but this pretty clearly isn't an answer to it

Comment: @DanielBeck The question is pretty clear: OP needs to know if `payment.html` page is loading...

Comment: Welp, all I can say is I don't think either half of that statement is correct ¯\_(ツ)_/¯